# Array of Arrays. Return left most and right most indexes

Tags: php, arrays

I have the following PHP array of arrays.

```
$current_date = date('Y-m-d';)

$readonly_db = array(
0 => array('2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05','2018-01-06','2018-01-07','2018-01-08','2018-01-09','2018-01-10','2018-01-11','2018-01-12','2018-01-13','2018-01-14'),
1 => array('2018-01-15','2018-01-16','2018-01-17','2018-01-18','2018-01-19','2018-01-20','2018-01-21','2018-01-22','2018-01-23','2018-01-24','2018-01-25','2018-01-26','2018-01-27','2018-01-28')

);
```

**How can I search this array of arrays for the current date and return it's left-most and right-most values? Perhaps by index?**

Example based on array above:

```
if ($current_date == '2018-01-14') {

$pay_period_start = '2018-01-01';
$pay_period_end = '2018-01-14';

}
```

I am currently researching arrays but array of arrays is quite challenging.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You can search the current date in these array of arrays easily but what do you mean by left most and right most?

Comment: Posted an update with example.

Comment: I have given the solution in reply. Kindly check please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$pay_period_start = '';
$pay_period_end = '';

$current_date = date(Y-m-d);
foreach($readonly_db as $arr){
     if(in_array($current_date, $arr)){
       $pay_period_start = current($arr);
       $pay_period_end = end($arr);
       break;
     }
 }
```

In this code you will need to run only single foreach loop.
Try this and let me know. Cheers :)

Comment: Very Nice. If you could please edit date(Y-m-d) to include single quotes that would be perfect.

Comment: You might also want to move the `date('Y-m-d')` outside of the loop so that you're not recalculating the date on every iteration.

Comment: yeah we can do that too. thanx fubar

Comment: Also use `break` when you find what you're looking for.

Comment: i did the change thanx @Barmar

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with simple `loop`.

```
   $readonly_db = array(
        0 => array('2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05','2018-01-06','2018-01-07','2018-01-08','2018-01-09','2018-01-10','2018-01-11','2018-01-12','2018-01-13','2018-01-14'),
        1 => array('2018-01-15','2018-01-16','2018-01-17','2018-01-18','2018-01-19','2018-01-20','2018-01-21','2018-01-22','2018-01-23','2018-01-24','2018-01-25','2018-01-26','2018-01-27','2018-01-28')
    );
    $pay_period_start = null;
    $pay_period_end = null;
    $current_date = date("Y-m-d");
    for($i=0;$i<count($readonly_db); $i++){
        $arr = $readonly_db[$i];
        for($j=0;$j<count($arr);$j++){
            if($arr[$j]==$current_date){
                $pay_period_start = $arr[0];
                $pay_period_end = $arr[(count($arr)-1)];
            }
        }
    }

    echo $pay_period_start.' '.$pay_period_end;
```

Comment: This was a functional answer. I chose foreach due to simplicity. Thank you for taking the time to help out!

Answer (score 0):

The following would print the first and last item of the child array if current date is found in any of the arrays.

**updated**

```
foreach($readonly_db as $dateArray) {
    foreach($dataArray as $dateString) {
        if ($dateString == $current_date) {
            // first item and last item in the array with current date.
            echo $dateArray[0] . ' ' . end($dateArray);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you could replace line starting with echo to `$pay_period_start = $dateArray[0]; $pay_period_end = end($dateArray);`

Answer (score 0):

You can foreach the array and use in_array to find the date you are looking for.

Once the date is found the values you are looking for is [0] and end of array.

```
Foreach($readonly_db as $val){
    if (in_array('2018-01-14', $val)) {
        $pay_period_start = $val[0];
        $pay_period_end = end($val);
     }
}
```

https://3v4l.org/VOWQ3

In_array returns true if the value `2018-01-14` is in the current subarray. No need to loop the subarrays and check each value.

Answer (score 0):

**Excel Spreadsheet to generate future years.**

*Does require some tweaking.*

Includes some pretty cool bonus features like JSON & PHP array concatenations.

These arrays are **auto generated** for you.

**No more** having to code around **WEEK 53**!!!

[clock.logic.xlsx](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lsFy35Fr59kvPyRB7myRWOugUYKSgz6v)

**Complete Functional Code for everyone to learn.**

```
<?php

// MOUNTAIN DAYLIGHT SAVINGS TIME
date_default_timezone_set('MST7MDT');

// = PHP Default TimeZone
print 'MOUNTAIN DAYLIGHT SAVINGS TIME';
print '<p>';

// = MySQL CURRDATE() in MySQL DATETIME Format.
$php_current_date = date('Y-m-d');

// 2018 Pay Periods
$input_arr =  array(
         1 => array('2018-01-01','2018-01-02','2018-01-03','2018-01-04','2018-01-05','2018-01-06','2018-01-07','2018-01-08','2018-01-09','2018-01-10','2018-01-11','2018-01-12','2018-01-13','2018-01-14'),
         2 => array('2018-01-15','2018-01-16','2018-01-17','2018-01-18','2018-01-19','2018-01-20','2018-01-21','2018-01-22','2018-01-23','2018-01-24','2018-01-25','2018-01-26','2018-01-27','2018-01-28'),
         3 => array('2018-01-29','2018-01-30','2018-01-31','2018-02-01','2018-02-02','2018-02-03','2018-02-04','2018-02-05','2018-02-06','2018-02-07','2018-02-08','2018-02-09','2018-02-10','2018-02-11'),
         4 => array('2018-02-12','2018-02-13','2018-02-14','2018-02-15','2018-02-16','2018-02-17','2018-02-18','2018-02-19','2018-02-20','2018-02-21','2018-02-22','2018-02-23','2018-02-24','2018-02-25'),
         5 => array('2018-02-26','2018-02-27','2018-02-28','2018-03-01','2018-03-02','2018-03-03','2018-03-04','2018-03-05','2018-03-06','2018-03-07','2018-03-08','2018-03-09','2018-03-10','2018-03-11'),
         6 => array('2018-03-12','2018-03-13','2018-03-14','2018-03-15','2018-03-16','2018-03-17','2018-03-18','2018-03-19','2018-03-20','2018-03-21','2018-03-22','2018-03-23','2018-03-24','2018-03-25'),
         7 => array('2018-03-26','2018-03-27','2018-03-28','2018-03-29','2018-03-30','2018-03-31','2018-04-01','2018-04-02','2018-04-03','2018-04-04','2018-04-05','2018-04-06','2018-04-07','2018-04-08'),
         8 => array('2018-04-09','2018-04-10','2018-04-11','2018-04-12','2018-04-13','2018-04-14','2018-04-15','2018-04-16','2018-04-17','2018-04-18','2018-04-19','2018-04-20','2018-04-21','2018-04-22'),
         9 => array('2018-04-23','2018-04-24','2018-04-25','2018-04-26','2018-04-27','2018-04-28','2018-04-29','2018-04-30','2018-05-01','2018-05-02','2018-05-03','2018-05-04','2018-05-05','2018-05-06'),
        10 => array('2018-05-07','2018-05-08','2018-05-09','2018-05-10','2018-05-11','2018-05-12','2018-05-13','2018-05-14','2018-05-15','2018-05-16','2018-05-17','2018-05-18','2018-05-19','2018-05-20'),
        11 => array('2018-05-21','2018-05-22','2018-05-23','2018-05-24','2018-05-25','2018-05-26','2018-05-27','2018-05-28','2018-05-29','2018-05-30','2018-05-31','2018-06-01','2018-06-02','2018-06-03'),
        12 => array('2018-06-04','2018-06-05','2018-06-06','2018-06-07','2018-06-08','2018-06-09','2018-06-10','2018-06-11','2018-06-12','2018-06-13','2018-06-14','2018-06-15','2018-06-16','2018-06-17'),
        13 => array('2018-06-18','2018-06-19','2018-06-20','2018-06-21','2018-06-22','2018-06-23','2018-06-24','2018-06-25','2018-06-26','2018-06-27','2018-06-28','2018-06-29','2018-06-30','2018-07-01'),
        14 => array('2018-07-02','2018-07-03','2018-07-04','2018-07-05','2018-07-06','2018-07-07','2018-07-08','2018-07-09','2018-07-10','2018-07-11','2018-07-12','2018-07-13','2018-07-14','2018-07-15'),
        15 => array('2018-07-16','2018-07-17','2018-07-18','2018-07-19','2018-07-20','2018-07-21','2018-07-22','2018-07-23','2018-07-24','2018-07-25','2018-07-26','2018-07-27','2018-07-28','2018-07-29'),
        16 => array('2018-07-30','2018-07-31','2018-08-01','2018-08-02','2018-08-03','2018-08-04','2018-08-05','2018-08-06','2018-08-07','2018-08-08','2018-08-09','2018-08-10','2018-08-11','2018-08-12'),
        17 => array('2018-08-13','2018-08-14','2018-08-15','2018-08-16','2018-08-17','2018-08-18','2018-08-19','2018-08-20','2018-08-21','2018-08-22','2018-08-23','2018-08-24','2018-08-25','2018-08-26'),
        18 => array('2018-08-27','2018-08-28','2018-08-29','2018-08-30','2018-08-31','2018-09-01','2018-09-02','2018-09-03','2018-09-04','2018-09-05','2018-09-06','2018-09-07','2018-09-08','2018-09-09'),
        19 => array('2018-09-10','2018-09-11','2018-09-12','2018-09-13','2018-09-14','2018-09-15','2018-09-16','2018-09-17','2018-09-18','2018-09-19','2018-09-20','2018-09-21','2018-09-22','2018-09-23'),
        20 => array('2018-09-24','2018-09-25','2018-09-26','2018-09-27','2018-09-28','2018-09-29','2018-09-30','2018-10-01','2018-10-02','2018-10-03','2018-10-04','2018-10-05','2018-10-06','2018-10-07'),
        21 => array('2018-10-08','2018-10-09','2018-10-10','2018-10-11','2018-10-12','2018-10-13','2018-10-14','2018-10-15','2018-10-16','2018-10-17','2018-10-18','2018-10-19','2018-10-20','2018-10-21'),
        22 => array('2018-10-22','2018-10-23','2018-10-24','2018-10-25','2018-10-26','2018-10-27','2018-10-28','2018-10-29','2018-10-30','2018-10-31','2018-11-01','2018-11-02','2018-11-03','2018-11-04'),
        23 => array('2018-11-05','2018-11-06','2018-11-07','2018-11-08','2018-11-09','2018-11-10','2018-11-11','2018-11-12','2018-11-13','2018-11-14','2018-11-15','2018-11-16','2018-11-17','2018-11-18'),
        24 => array('2018-11-19','2018-11-20','2018-11-21','2018-11-22','2018-11-23','2018-11-24','2018-11-25','2018-11-26','2018-11-27','2018-11-28','2018-11-29','2018-11-30','2018-12-01','2018-12-02'),
        25 => array('2018-12-03','2018-12-04','2018-12-05','2018-12-06','2018-12-07','2018-12-08','2018-12-09','2018-12-10','2018-12-11','2018-12-12','2018-12-13','2018-12-14','2018-12-15','2018-12-16'),
        26 => array('2018-12-17','2018-12-18','2018-12-19','2018-12-20','2018-12-21','2018-12-22','2018-12-23','2018-12-24','2018-12-25','2018-12-26','2018-12-27','2018-12-28','2018-12-29','2018-12-30')
        );

$current_pay_period_start = '';
$current_pay_period_end = '';

// Search array of arrays for $php_current_date
foreach($input_arr as $arr){

    // if $php_current_date is found...
    if (in_array($php_current_date, $arr)) {

        // get left most index
        $current_pay_period_start = current($arr);
        // get right most index
        $current_pay_period_end = end($arr);
        print 'Php Current Date: ' . $php_current_date;
        print '<br>';
        print 'Current Pay Period Start: ' . $current_pay_period_start;
        print '<br>';
        print 'Current Pay Period End: ' . $current_pay_period_end;
        exit;
    }
}

print 'PHP Current Date: NOT FOUND in Array of Arrays.';
print '<br>';
print 'Current Pay Period Start: NOT FOUND in Array of Arrays.';
print '<br>';
print 'Current Pay Period End: NOT FOUND in Array of Arrays.';

?>
```